# Linked list, node adresses

Tags: c

My assigment is to display address of each node in linked list. The trouble is that all the adresses are the same, which in not right. Help would be appreciated. I hope that you have a great day :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct element 
{
    float x;
    struct element * next;
};

void show(struct element *lista)
{
    struct element *temp=lista;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
    printf("%f\n",temp->x);
    printf("%p\n",&temp->x);
    temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct element *lista=NULL;
    struct element *wsk=malloc(sizeof(struct element));
    wsk->x=5.5;
    wsk->next=NULL;
    lista=wsk;

    struct element *wsk2=malloc(sizeof(struct element));
    wsk2->x=1.3;
    wsk2->next=lista;
    lista=wsk2;

    struct element *wsk3=malloc(sizeof(struct element));
    wsk3->x=8.1;
    wsk3->next=lista;
    lista=wsk3;
    
    show(lista);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cannot duplicate. I get 3 different addresses. https://onlinegdb.com/Chwn0ooGV

Comment: True they are all diffrent. Guess im little to tired to have noticed :). Thanks for the help anyway.